# Operation count for Trapezoidal Integration vs Romberg Integration

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, approximate-integration

I have been working with computing and numerical integration, and I have to juxtapose the operations required for Trapezoidal and Romberg for $n$ points to a certain error tolerance. For trapezoidal it is obviously $O(n)$. However, I am unsure of the operation count for Romberg, which i assume is either $O\left(n^2\right)$ or $O\left(2^n\right)$.

**Can someone teach me what the operation count for Romberg integration is for $n$ points?**

Comment: Wiki provides [a good example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method) with comparison

Comment: I have read that before posting. It only comments on the stability and error. And my small brain can only comprehend it is at least approx. 3n